# Display user register form in template?

Tags: theming, forms, paragraphs

I'm working on a design heavy site and one of the sections created via the Paragraphs module requires to display the `user_register` form.

I'm currently doing this in the `paragraphs-item--myparagraph.tpl.php` file with the following code:

```
<?php
  $form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
  print drupal_render($form);
?>
```

This works for showing the form but the problem is that if there are form validation errors, they don't show. I have read that the issue is rendering the form [too](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19347/why-does-retrieving-a-form-via-drupal-get-form-from-another-module-not-include-a) [late](http://pixeljets.com/blog/be-careful-drupalgetform-theme-layer/) but I can't see how I adapt this to Paragraph entities. I have tried using [mytheme_preprocess_entity](http://dropbucket.org/node/7016) to pass the form in but I can't render it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar recently, and I opted for the [Block Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/blockreference) module.

1. I created a new paragraph called Block Reference
2. Added a block reference field
3. Selected "system blocks" as being referable under the field settings
4. Selected the user login block

and wham bam thank you mam ive got a user login block in a paragraph.

Comment: Cool, thank you! I ended up just rendering the form in the page template instead but I'm sure this will come in handy

Answer (score 0):

I ended up displaying the form directly on the page instead.

`template.php`

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (drupal_is_front_page()){
        if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
            $form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
            $variables['register_form'] = drupal_render($form);
        }
    }
}
```

`page--front.tpl.php`

```
<?php print $register_form; ?>
```